# Github ssh key accidently replaced

Tags: github, ssh

I accidentally replaced the ssh keys which were used to access the git hub using ssh. 
How can I change it to new keys?

Comment: github has a web interface for that

Answer (score 0):

That's easy, go to https://github.com/settings/keys and click on 'New SSH key' to add your new key